# Using non-observables in custom binding handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I want to work with variables in knockout.js custom bindings. Especially in event handlers inside the `init` callback.

Example:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.test = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var $element = $(element);
        var f = valueAccessor();

        $element.mousedown(function(e) {
            f = true;
        });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var f = valueAccessor();
    }
};
```

Model:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.flag = false;
};
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nm6hzbok/1/).

The problem is: If `mousedown` is fired on the element, the `flag` is not getting updated in the model.

The problem is this line:

```
var f = valueAccessor();
```

The value is copied and not the reference. Booleans are primitives.

I can make `flag` observable, so it's a function and i have the reference inside the handler. But i don't want an observable... I just don't need the 'notify listeners on change'-feature here.

I could also do a wrapper function or something... but... a function just to get the reference of an Boolean?

I need this feature just to report the "state" of my binding. External functions need this information sometimes, but they don't want to get knockout-noticed on a value change.

Is there a best practice or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding

> i just don't need the 'notify listeners on change'-feature here

Think if that's a strong enough reason not to use an observable. Are there any *actual disadvantages* if you use an observable – or *actual advantages* if you don't?

Knockout is full of observables and other, more complex things. You don't really gain anything if you "save" an observable. Use them where they provide benefit, that's what the framework is for, after all.

If you have no subscribers for an observable and just use it out of convenience to hold some sort of internal state – that's a perfectly fine reason to use an observable.

If you absolutely, positively *must* avoid an observable, you can pass the name of a viewModel property:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.test = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var propertyName = valueAccessor();

        $(element).mousedown(function(e) {
            viewModel[propertyName] = true;
        }).mouseup(function(e) {
            viewModel[propertyName] = false;
        });
    }
};
```

and

```
<input type="text" data-bind="test: 'flag'">
```

Comment: It is a performance reason. I'm going to use this binding veeeeeeeery often and knockout is calling every function which uses the observable. Anyway...your solution likes nice, i'm going to give it a try ;)

Comment: Out of curiosity: Can you provide a skeleton example on jsFiddle that suffers from performance problems when you use an observable for that?

Comment: yes i can prepare one, BUT: the core information of your solution is: "don't use primitives because you need the reference". In this case an observable is nothing else than any kind of wrapperobject/wrapperfunction. I don't want any kind of wrapper...just to write a boolean. This just not feels the right way. And an observable is the heaviest kind of wrapper, because it has this notification things in it. Using wrappers costs performance.

Comment: *"Using wrappers costs performance."* - definitely. However, sometimes using them smartly may help countering the effect. In the end I just wanted to know whether you had good reasons, and you seem to have them, which is all right. If you come up with a negative example I'd still like to have a look, maybe I can think of a way to improve things.

Comment: here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/nm6hzbok/2/ it is nothing special. I just thought there is some kind of "best pratice" to write primitives back to the model. Your solution looks like a "hack" but if it works i'll use and upvote it ;)

Comment: My solution is no hack. It simply is the consequence of the fact that primitive values (like your `flag`) are always *copied* between function calls. You can not reference them. You can only reference the *object* they are attached to, which means you must have object reference (`viewModel`) and the property name (`'flag'`) when you want to change the flag in your viewModel instance.

Comment: ok, but just one addition: viewModel == rowContext if inside a foreach loop. My flag is 'global' , so i have to write bindingContext[$root]['flag'];

Comment: That's correct. Regarding your fiddle: **1)** You say your flag is global, but your fiddle does not reflect that. There you have 1000 flags. **2)** If you don't want to update the text then don't use the text binding. **3)** I don't experience any slowness in your sample. — In short, I still can't see your use case, or your sample fiddle can't convey it.

Comment: 1) i want the binding to be generic, it is the devs decision if he passes 'flag' or '$root.flag' to the binding, but your right the fiddle is useless. You have to comment the observable and uncomment the boolean 2) in every function the observable is accessed, ko calls the function on a change. I used the binding, just because its easyness...it doesn't matter what is accessing the observable (function or binding) 3) you have to measure it. -- This was a "best practise" question. As already said, I know the problem. I just thought there is a trick or a ko.util to handle this primitives thing.

Comment: *"in every function the observable is accessed, ko calls the function on a change."* not true, only functions that are *themselves* observable (`ko.computed`) will be cascaded. The others will behave normally.

Comment: ohh thx! I learned it different...i think i have to rethink something ;)

Comment: Looks like there was some benefit in my persistence, after all. :)